# Partially using Spring Dependency Injection during migration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, migrate

I´m currently migrating an existing project to Spring. I´ve started to use dependency injection on some newer components that are loosely coupled, the project itself is however very messy, tightly coupled and it´s impossible for me to use DI entirely and I need to change the code **step by step**.

The "starting point" of where dependency injection is used is a component, that itself has also some dependencies which cannot be injected and have to be passed through a constructor. **See this example**

```
@Component
public class FromHellToDependencyInjectionHeaven extends ComplicatedMessyBaseComponent{

    @Autowired
    private InjectedComponentFromHeavenOne componentOne;

    @Autowired
    private InjectedComponentFromHeavenTwo componentTwo;

    private UninjectableMess uninjectableMess;

    /*
     * Constructor that has to stay for now because of the ComplicatedMessyBaseComponent
     * clashes with @Component
     */
    public FromHellToDependencyInjectionHeaven(MessyDependencyOne dependencyOne, 
    MessyDependencyTwo dependencyTwo, UninjectableMess uninjectableMess){
        super(dependencyOne,dependencyTwo);
        this.uninjectableMess = uninjectableMess;
    }

}
```

Here comes the problem:

To use **@Autowired**, the component that uses the dependencies has to be either a **@Service** or a **@Component**, otherwise I get

> Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean
>   (@Component|@Service|...)

But when I do that, I run into complications with the existing constructor that I cannot remove.

> Class doesn't contain matching constructor for autowiring

One idea was to tell Spring to **disable the constructor dependency injection** for this class, but I haven´t found any possible solution for that.

**How can I partially use dependency injection in my project?**

Comment: Remove `@Autowired` and just assign values in the constructor (which is even the recommended way of doing dependency injection). Also a Spring bean can also be the result of an `@Bean` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. What do you mean with assign them in the constructor? For my understanding, in order to use a bean I would need DI as well

Comment: Define an `@Bean` method to specify what/how to do injection for the `FromHellToDependencyInjectionHeaven` and/or just add the `InjectedComponentFromHeavenOne` and `InjectedComponentFromHeavenTwo` as constructor arguments.

Comment: @M.Deinum Understood. Lind of a manual injection. My example is very simplified, let´s say there are 6 different "InjectedComponentFromHeavenOne " in existence that are having dependencies between each other and can be used independently. That would require me to create one bean per dependency with a manual creation of it´s co-dependencies, which is quite a bit overhead. But I´ll give it a try, thx